# Guice: Inject a class bound by another module?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have the following classes:

```
public class CacheModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bindConstant().annotatedWith(Names.named(TIMEOUT")).to(60);
        // ...etc.
    }
}

public class DefaultCacheAdaptor implements CacheAdaptor {
    private CacheModule bootstrapper = new CacheModule();

    @Named("TIMEOUT") private int timeout;

    // other fields omitted for brevity

    public DefaultCacheAdaptor() {
        super();

        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(bootstrapper);

        @Named("TIMEOUT") int t = injector.getInstance(Integer.class);
        setTimeout(t);
    }
}

public class QueueModule extennds AbstractModule {
    @Override
    public void configure() {
        bind(CacheAdaptor.class).to(DefaultCacheAdaptor.class);
    }
}

public class DefaultQueueAdaptor implements QueueAdaptor {
    private QueueModule bootstrapper = new QueueModule();

    private CacheAdaptor cacheAdaptor;

    public DefaultQueueAdaptor() {
        super();

        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(bootstrapper);

        setCacheAdaptor(injector.getInstance(CacheAdaptor.class));
    }
}
```

The `CacheModule`/`CacheAdaptor`/`DefaultCacheAdaptor` is located in a different JAR than `QueueModule`/`QueueAdaptor`/`DefaultQueueAdaptor`, and so the latter JAR depends on the former JAR at runtime (obviously).

The purpose of coding things this way is to allow the `CacheModule` to boostrap/inject the entire object graph under `DefaultCacheAdaptor` when the user writes:

```
CacheAdaptor cacheAdaptor = new DefaultCacheAdaptor();
```

Ditto for the `QueueAdaptor`.

It just so *happens* to be that the `QueueAdaptor` gets injected with a `CacheAdaptor`.

However, `DefaultCacheAdaptor` is the "root" of its own object tree, and should **always** be injected by the `CacheModule`.

So I ask: **how can I bind `DefaultCacheAdaptor` to `CacheAdaptor` from inside `QueueModule`, but ensure that the `DefaultCacheAdaptor` is itself initialized/bootstrapped by the `CacheModule`?**

Comment: Local variables can't receive parameters, so your `@Named("TIMEOUT") int t` variable in DefaultCacheAdaptor's constructor probably actually looks like `int t = injector.getInstance(Integer.class, Names.named("TIMEOUT"));`.

Comment: Thanks @JeffBowman (+1) - I haven't actually ran this code yet. It may very well produce a runtime exception, but in Eclipse it does not produce a compile-time error. But that is *exactly* how I have it coded up (I'm using Guice 3.0). Also, any ideas as to the question I'm asking here? Thanks again!

Comment: Clarification: "An annotation on a local variable declaration is never retained in the binary representation." —[JLS 9.6.1.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/interfaces.html#9.6.1.2) So the annotation isn't illegal, but it'll never stick around long enough for Guice to see it or use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest it sounds like this problem isn't actually one of Guice, but instead the standard problem across software engineering: ensuring your dependencies do what they claim to do. QueueModule shouldn't concern itself about whether DefaultCacheAdaptor holds up to its general contract. Instead, write a unit test for DefaultCacheAdaptor that guarantees that it bootstraps itself, then use it in QueueModule without a second thought.

This is especially true because DefaultCacheAdaptor has a completely unrelated injector tree. You should be able to use DefaultCacheAdaptor opaquely, and stop concerning QueueAdaptor with its implementation details. Its bootstrapping is part of its implementation, not its API.

Even if you were to merge the two Injector graphs into one (by [injecting the Injector](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html) and calling [createChildInjector](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Injector.html#createChildInjector%28com.google.inject.Module...%29), for instance), there's very little way to guarantee at compile time that bindings you need in other modules will exist, because `Module`s work at runtime. Your best bet is to write a unit test. You can fail a little faster by calling [`requireBinding`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/AbstractModule.html#requireBinding%28java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29), which will fail at Injector creation if that particular dependency doesn't end up satisfied externally.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Bowman (+1) - that said, the way that I have everything coded up right now, will the `CacheModule` be invoked and used to inject the `DefaultCacheAdaptor` when the `QueueModule` is used to create an `Injector`?

Comment: @IAmYourFaja I don't see why it wouldn't, unless you somehow have another `@Inject` constructor that the `DefaultQueueAdaptor` injector would prefer over the no-arg constructor you wrote above.